# AWS "Private registry authentication for tasks" not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ecs, docker-registry

I try to set up ECS to be working with GitHub private registry following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html) instructions, but constantly getting this error when deploying ECS Task:

```
Status reason   CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ghcr.io/a/b/c, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: permission_denied: The token provided does not match expected s
```

Here is task execution role in task definition:
[image]

Here is IAM role itself:
[image]

But it doesn't work. At the same time [Private registry authentication for container instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth-container-instances.html) works fine. Has anyone had a successful experience with configuring ECS private registry authentication? Please, share how you did it. What I missed in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its the actual permission on the token?

I was able to get it working with these steps (code in terraform notation, hope that is ok):

1. Create a token on GH with the `read:packages` scope

   - If you have SSO on the org you need to configure it for the token as well
2. Create a CMK and Secret for the token

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "github_token_secrets" {
  enable_key_rotation = true
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "github_pat_token" {
  name                    = "github-pat-token"
  description             = "The Github secure token"
  kms_key_id              = aws_kms_key.github_token_secrets.arn
  recovery_window_in_days = 0
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "github_pat_token" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.github_pat_token.id
  secret_string = jsonencode(
    {
      "username" = var.github_user,
      "password" = var.github_token
    }
  )
}
```

3. Make sure role is properly setup

   - ecs-tasks on AssumeRole
   - Decrypt on CMK
   - GetSecretValue on secret

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs-agent-role" {
  name = "agent-role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })

  inline_policy {
    name = "inline-policy"

    policy = jsonencode({
      Version = "2012-10-17"
      "Statement" = [
        {
          "Effect" = "Allow",
          "Action" = [
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
          ],
          "Resource" = [
            aws_secretsmanager_secret.github_pat_token.id,
            aws_kms_key.github_token_secrets.arn
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

4. Use the iam and secrets arn on task definition

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs_task" {
  family                = "worker"
  container_definitions = data.template_file.petclinic-task-image-definition.rendered
  execution_role_arn    = aws_iam_role.ecs-agent-role.arn


  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      "name": "some-name",
      "image": "ghcr.io/.....",

      ...

      "repositoryCredentials": {
        "credentialsParameter": aws_secretsmanager_secret.github_pat_token.arn
      }
    }
  ])
}
```

PS: Not sure if you already solved it but sending something here in case somebody else reaches it while trying to set it up (like I did )